# Is "more better" ungrammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, comparative-constructions

I want to find out whether these sentences are grammatically incorrect:

> It is more better than your book

or

> It is far more better than your book

Comment: You should only use "more better" when you're intentionally imitating "illiterate" (or at least very "casual") speech.  (It would not be that unusual for a college educated individual (in the US) to use "more better" when speaking in a jocular style, however.)

Comment: No. You have to use _much_ in your meaning because the adjective is comparative.

Answer (score 4):

Neither are correct. "better" is a [comparative](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting) form of "good", so you do not need to (and should not) say "more better": say either:

> It is better than your book.

or

> It is far better than your book.

Comment: Just FYI, though, "more better" is pretty frequently used ironically these days by the hipsters and the whatnot to simply mean "better".

Also, while I think no one would responsibly advocate this use, I think you could make an argument for saying "peaches are more better than apricots than plums are better than pluots".  If you wanted to be that kind of person.

Comment: Also, "much better" which I think is less formal and a little more common  (at least in AmE) than "far better".

Answer (score 0):

If you study the grammar point comparison forms of adjectives you will find that

1 certain adjectives have the endings -er/est

2 others use more/most before the adjective

3 some have irregular forms, e.g. good better best

Using "more better" is against normal grammar, and if it is used it is uneducated and substandard.

http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/comparing-adjectives/

Answer (score 0):

I agree; it is simply redundant. It's like saying "more, more good" and you'd never (at least one can hope) say, "This book is more, more good than your book." The usage of "more better" suggests a substandard education.