# Better, more better or much better, which is correct?

Tags: comparative-degree

Yesterday, I asked one of my students how he was. He answered, "I am more better." I told him that "I am (much) better" would do. He answered, I was already better yesterday, and I am better than I was yesterday." It made me think twice. Was I wrong with my correction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "more better" ungrammatical?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47284/is-more-better-ungrammatical)

Answer (score 1):

No, you aren't wrong.

The simple rule is this that you use *'much'* ( instead of very, more etc ) *with 2nd degree of adjective*.

What your student should have said was this,

> I am feeling better than yesterday

or,

> I am feeling much better than yesterday

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, "better" = adj. in comparion. "A little" or "rather" or "much" = adv. They modify "better" to intensify the degree of "better". It is enough to use "rather better", "a little better", or "much better". In "More better", "more" is redundant because both "better and more" means increase, intensity in comparison. However, it is okay with "more and more; less and less", and "adj.+er and adj.+er" to express increase in comparion. For example, "I am less and less healthy when I am older and older"; "He is more and more grown-up."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).