# What is a "grammar point"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, terminology

I found [lots of posts](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Grammar%20Point%22) use a phrase "grammar point". [For example](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/51188/112757),

> If you study the **grammar point** comparison forms of adjectives you will find that ...

where comparison forms of adjectives appears to be **one grammar point**.

Is "grammar point" a term in grammar? What is a "grammar point"? Could anything relate to grammar be **one grammar point**?

---

> A: If you study the forms of adjectives you will find that . . .
>
> B: would you provide some reference to that **grammar point**?

Comment: "grammar point" is not a grammatical term. It merely means "grammar issue".

Comment: @Gustavson Thank you. Is "grammar issue" a grammatical term?

Comment: No - neither of them are grammatical terms. The use of "point" here is redundant. The line you quoted could be written more simply as: If you study the forms of adjectives you will find that . . .